# Android instrument test with Espresso fails: NoSuchMethodError get() in javax.inject.Provider

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-espresso

When I run my Android instrument test, Espresso class initialization fails with the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method get()Ljava/lang/Object; in class Ljavax/inject/Provider; or its super classes (declaration of 'javax.inject.Provider' appears in /data/app/com.myapp.mock.debug-2/base.apk)
at android.support.test.espresso.DaggerBaseLayerComponent.idlingResourceRegistry(DaggerBaseLayerComponent.java:101)
at android.support.test.espresso.Espresso.<clinit>(Espresso.java:52)
...
```

I don't know if it is relevant, but my project uses Kotlin.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to add the following in the proguard file of the application:

```
-keep class javax.inject.* { *; }
```

Otherwise the `get()` method is removed by Proguard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using DI in your project. Refer Donn Felker blog,

http://www.donnfelker.com/android-studio-espresso-2-0-classnotfoundexception/

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I use DI with dagger 1.2.2 in my app, but the suggested fix did not help. Thanx anyway.